# Convert LDAP timestamp to different format in Linux shell

Tags: shell, date, openldap

I use the `ldapsearch` command in Linux to get LDAP information about users. The last authentication time is returned in a format that seems to be called "FileTime":

```
authTimestamp: 20200804154203Z
```

How can I convert this timestamp with common Linux shell commands to a more readable date, like `2020-08-04 15:42`? I tried using the `date` command but it doesn't recognize the given input format...

```
> date --date "20200415062835Z"
date: invalid date ‘20200415062835Z’
```

It seems that `date` only allows special output formats to be defined. In other words, I can print the current date in the format that LDAP returns (`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ`), but I find no way of telling `date` that it should use `+%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ` as input format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the exact input format of the LDAP `authTimestamp` (e.g., `20200415062835Z`) I came up with a fairly simple function to convert it to `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format in case the input matches a given regular expression.

```
function _convert_ldap_timestamp() {
    ts=$1
    if [[ "${ts}" =~ ^[0-9]{14}Z$ ]]; then
        echo "${ts:0:4}-${ts:4:2}-${ts:6:2} ${ts:8:2}:${ts:10:2}:${ts:12:2}"
    fi
}
```

Example execution:

```
> _convert_ldap_timestamp 20200804154203Z
2020-08-04 15:42:03
```